# Split Java list by predicate and map different functions for each sub list

Tags: java, collections

I need help with a fairly common task, but i can't do it clearly and well.

What I have: list of integers.

What i want: split array on two by predicate and apply different functions for each.

For example, my ugly solution:

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> collect = 
        Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
                .collect(Collectors.<Integer>partitioningBy(e -> e % 2 == 0));

List<Integer> result = collect.get(true)
        .stream()
        .map(x -> x * x)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

result.addAll(collect.get(false)
        .stream()
        .map(x -> x + 2)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));


System.out.println(result);
```

But i think that task can be solved in FP way, with collectors, but don't know how.
And yea, i can use only Java 8 without third party libraries like Guava/Apache Commons and etc.

Hope you can help and teach me new approach!

Thanks and sorry for my english!

Comment: Do you need the output List to first contain all the elements from the first partition and then all the elements of the second partition, or can you keep the original order of the input List?

Comment: Best to keep order of the original list.

Comment: Your “ugly” solution is actually a straight-forward solution. You should keep in mind that the collectors do not guaranty a mutable list. If you use `Collectors.partitioningBy(e -> e % 2 == 0, Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))` you can do the post-processing like `List<Integer> result = collect.get(true); result.replaceAll(x -> x * x); collect.get(false).replaceAll(x -> x + 2); result.addAll(collect.get(false));`

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the partitioning if you don't need to change the order of the input `Stream`:

```
List<Integer> result =
    Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
          .map(x -> x % 2 == 0 ? x * x : x + 2)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output:

```
[3, 4, 5, 16, 7, 36, 9, 64, 11]
```

If you want the partitions to be grouped, you can use a custom `Collector`:

```
List<Integer> result =
    Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
          .collect(Collector.of (
              () -> {
                  Map<Boolean,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
                  map.put (true, new ArrayList<> ());
                  map.put (false, new ArrayList<> ());
                  return map;
              },
              (m,i) -> {
                  if (i % 2 == 0) 
                      m.get (true).add(i*i); 
                  else 
                      m.get (false).add(i+2);
              },
              (b1,b2)-> {
                  b1.putAll (b2);
                  return b1;
              },
              m -> {
                  List<Integer> l = m.get(true);
                  l.addAll (m.get(false));
                  return l;
              }));
```

Output:

```
[4, 16, 36, 64, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```

Comment: bulky solution!
and if the order was not important how would you write?

Comment: @aarexer I also answered that. See top of the answer.

Comment: Based on your first variant, you could use `List<Integer> result = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(x -> x % 2)) .map(x -> x % 2 == 0 ? x * x : x + 2) .collect(Collectors.toList());` if changing the order is required.

Answer (score 0):

You could use groupingBy instead:

```
    Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> grouped = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e % 2 == 0));        
    System.out.println("" + grouped);
```

Output:

```
{false=[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], true=[2, 4, 6, 8]}
```

Then process Map as you need.

Comment: And how is it different from my solution?
In both ways i need to write smth like:

List<Integer> result = collect.get(true)
        .stream()
        .map(x -> x * x)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

result.addAll(collect.get(false)
        .stream()
        .map(x -> x + 2)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));

Comment: At the point you may stream map entries (using .forEach() for example) and process those dependand on key vaue.